# use mdtool command line to compile a c# solution on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, mdtool

When I try to compile my c# solution with mdtool (Xamarin) with the Release configuration it compile as a Debug configuration. Someone can help me?
The command

$ mdtool build -t:Build -c:Release test.sln

Comment: I found how to fix as Xamarin use Release|x86 configuration to run c# project. $mdtool build -t:Build -c:"Release|x86" test.sln

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
mdtool build '--configuration:Release' test.sln
```

run `mdtool --help` to see other options

Comment: Hi Thanks should be the same as the help mentions -c = --configuration. anyway i tried but the result is the same. the Debug build is created.